# Why won't my header show in MS Word using OOXML & Word JS API

Tags: ms-word, openxml, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

Trying to use Visual Studio 2017 to do this: Why is the header not showing in MS WORD? I tried to simplified from a real dotx document that was saved as XML. I managed to make it work with plain body text and even floating images in the body. But before I could work on images in header/footer, I am trying to test it with plain text in the header, but I just can't seem to figure out how to make it work. Thank you! See full XML script below:

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
        <Relationship Id="rId6" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header1.xml"/>
        <Relationship Id="rId7" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header2.xml"/>
      </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:document xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" >
        <w:sectPr>
          <w:headerReference r:id="rId6" w:type="first"/>
          <w:headerReference r:id="rId7" w:type="default"/>
        </w:sectPr>
        <w:body>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:rPr>
                <w:noProof/>
              </w:rPr>
              <w:t>testing 193</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:body>
      </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/header1.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:hdr xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
        <w:p>
          <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Header"/>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r>
            <w:t>helo this is first header</w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:hdr>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
  <pkg:part pkg:name="/word/header2.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
      <w:hdr xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
        <w:p>
          <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Header"/>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r>
            <w:t>helo this is default header</w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:hdr>
    </pkg:xmlData>
  </pkg:part>
</pkg:package>
```

Comment: Please show your office.js code.

Comment: Everything else is from: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-Load-and-write-Open-XML

I merely replaced the SimpleImage.xml with my XML script above, to learn how these stuff works, as a newbie. Thanks Rick for your attention.

Comment: Do you get errors? What are they? From a glance at the Open XML I'd say a big problem is that `<w:sectPr>` must *follow* `<w:body>, not precede it.

Comment: Nope Cindy, to my surprise, it's executed very clean, no errors.

Comment: I've also moved <w:sectPr></w:sectPr> to just right below <w:body>. Still no dice.

Comment: If someone could give me a simple sample of OOXML that shows header/footer via Office-JS in Word, that would be great. I can't seem to find such sample online, it's always done using simply Office-JS, not OOXML coercion type. The reason I need this in OOXML is because I want to put a floating image in the header and all the way to the edge of the paper, beyond the margin, and it appears that this cannot be done via JS API but OOXML. If I can get a sample of header insertion using OOXML coercion type, I should be able to back-engineer my way there. Thanks again follks!!!

Comment: Is it because I use: setSelectedDataAsync viz.  Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(myXML, { coercionType: 'ooxml' });

That's like writing to the active selection in the document, which is obviously not the header by default in a newly opened document. If so, what is the recommendation?